# What does this mean (function($) {}

Tags: javascript, function

if I write this code:

```
(function($){})
```

Does it mean that in this function I can write instead of word "function" just "$".

Thank you for explaining this.

Comment: It's a function taking one parameter called `$`.

Comment: I bet you're missing the end of what is: `(function ($) {})(jQuery);`, or the beginning of what is: `jQuery(function ($) {});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What it means is that $ can be used with a particular meaning inside of that context. This sort of thing is frequently used when variables like `$` are used by two or more toolkits. For example, jQuery often is written like this to handle a document-ready method:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#div').something()...
});
```

That way, you can be sure that `$` will mean `jQuery` in that context even if you called `jQuery.noConflict` elsewhere.

This particular syntax, `(function($){})` is typically done like this:

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

That is done to create an anonymous function and call it with a particular context. Often it's used to do something like pass a particular iteration of a loop to an AJAX operation (like if you want to make 5 ajax calls inside of a loop that runs five times). Example:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    (function(index) {
        $.ajax(url, { data... }, success(data) {
            if (data.y == index)....
        });
    })(x);
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain that jQuery explicitly passes the `jQuery` object to this function, which is denoted by the `$` parameter. It doesn't magically happen

Answer (score 1):

It is an anonymous function , taking $ as an argument to use it in local scope.

It can be called like this :

`(function($){ SOME_OPERATIONS_WITH_$ ;})(theObjectBeingPassedAsDollar)`

eg. jQuery object can be passed to this instance, and it would be used in the anonymous function as $

This will alert `HelloWorld` :

```
(function($){ alert($.one + $.two); })( {'one':'Hello','two':'World'} )
```

**demo:http://jsfiddle.net/Pg9s4/**